# Android - AsyncTask e ProgressDialog

Tags: java, android, json, multithreading, asynctask

Olá, galera.
Estou iniciando na área Mobile há pouco tempo e estou com alguns problemas com a questão da experiência do usuário no meu App.

No meu App, ele obtem um JSON do servidor através de um `AsyncTask`.
Abaixo uma classe bem cumprida, mas que basicamente faz:

- `onPreExecute`: Inicia um `ProgressDialog`.
- `doInBackground`: Busca o JSON no servidor usando `OkHttp`.
- `onPostExecute`: Preenche uma `List` com o conteúdo do JSON e finaliza o `ProgressDialog`.

  ```
  class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{private ProgressDialog dialog;

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      Resources resource = getResources();
      String aguarde = resource.getString(R.string.aguarde);
      String sincronizando = resource.getString(R.string.sincronizando_dados);
      dialog = ProgressDialog.show(rootView.getContext(), aguarde,sincronizando, true);
  }

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
      try {
          OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
          Request request = new Request.Builder().url(ServerUtil.URL_PROPRIETARIOS).build();
          Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
          return response.body().string();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          error += e.getMessage();
      }
      return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
      super.onPostExecute(s);
      if(s != null){
          try {
              JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
              proprietarios = new Proprietarios(jsonArray);
              adapter = new ProprietarioAdapter(rootView.getContext(), proprietarios.getList(), gadoProprietario);
              lista.setAdapter(adapter);
          } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              error += e.getMessage();
          } catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
      if(proprietarios != null && proprietarios.getList().size() > 0){
          for(Proprietario proprietario : proprietarios.getList()){
              new GadoProprietarioTask(proprietario.getId()).execute();
          }
      }
      dialog.dismiss();
  }
  ```

Minha dúvida:

Ex.: Tento me conectar e recebo o JSON em menos de **100ms**, não existe necessidade de abrir um `ProgressDialog` e ser fechado quase instantaneamente. Então quero evitar esse feito de abre e fecha instantâneo quero que ele só comece depois de **200ms** e se der **201ms** ele não feche imediatamente fique mais **200ms** por exemplo.

Se a explicação não estiver boa o suficiente falem que eu refaço, desde já agradeço.

Obs.: `AsyncTask` é a melhor maneira pra isso que eu estou fazendo? Se souberem alguma melhor comentem ai!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando menos você manter a interface do usuário ocupada, melhor. Sinceramente, não vejo isso como um problema mas concordo que isso esteticamente vai ficar estranho.

Neste caso, você vai precisar remover o `ProgressDialog` da classe `NetworkTask` e passa-lo para o escopo qual vc está executando esta task.

Mas não é só isso, você também vai ter que agendar um `CountDownTimer` ou um `Handler` para disparar a task depois de um determinado intervalo.

#### Exemplo usando `Handler`

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new NetworkTask().execute();
    }
}, 200);
```

#### Exemplo usando `Timer`

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new NetworkTask().execute()
    }
}, 200);
```

Claro, não esqueça de exibir o `ProgressDialog` antes do timer que você criou para que ele apareça antes da execução da tarefa.

Também não esqueça de levar em consideração que quando estamos testando networking, geralmente o server por ser de desenvolvimento, pode estar mais rápido para demandar por *n* fatores tipo, latência, disponibilidade do server, quantidade de dados a serem consultados, enfim. talvez você nem precise fazer essa mudança para o release do seu app.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Valeu, já tinha encontrado aqui uns exemplos com CountDownTimer que suprem a minha necessidade, mas você me deu a resposta que eu estava precisando. Realmente tem a questão de latência e N fatores a mais no servidor e talvez nem seja necessário fora do ambiente de desenvolvimento, mas realmente eu estava incomodado com o UX do Dialog kkkk. Valeu!